# Binding a Child-Array horizontal to a Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to fill a DataGridView with a datastructure like the following.

```
{
   "HAN":123456789,
   "Attributes":[
      {
         "Name":"bool",
         "Value":false
      },
      {
         "Name":"int",
         "Value":123
      },
      {
         "Name":"string",
         "Value":"empty string"
      }
   ]
}
```

In my application it should look like this:

[image]

The datastructer in C# looks like:

```
public class HanAttribute : BaseM {

        private string _han;
        [BsonElement(nameof(HAN))]
        public string HAN {
            get { return _han; }
            set {
                if (_han != value) {
                    _han = value;
                    IsModified = true;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HAN));
                }
            }
        }

        private BindingList<AttributeValue> _attributes = new BindingList<AttributeValue>();
        [BsonElement(nameof(Attributes))]
        public BindingList<AttributeValue> Attributes {
            get { return _attributes; }
            set {
                if (_attributes != value) {
                    _attributes = value;
                    _attributes.ListChanged -= _content_ListChanged;
                    _attributes.ListChanged += _content_ListChanged;
                    IsModified = true;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Attributes));
                }
            }
        }

        #region Events

        private void _content_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add) {
                IsModified = true;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Attributes));
        }

        private void _content_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) {
            if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged) {
                IsModified = true;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Attributes));
        }

        #endregion Events

    }
```

```
public class AttributeValue : BaseM {

        private string _name;
        [BsonElement(nameof(Name))]
        public string Name {
            get { return _name; }
            set {
                if (_name != value) {
                    _name = value;
                    IsModified = true;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
                }
            }
        }

        private dynamic _value;
        [BsonElement(nameof(Value))]
        public dynamic Value {
            get { return _value; }
            set {
                if (_value != value) {
                    _value = value;
                    IsModified = true;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I generate the columns by code and added the DataPropertyName to the HAN-Column. There it works.

But I don't know how to achieve a result where the array Attributes will be bound and displayed like in the picture.